# Can I set up a optimally secure connection between Apache and Wildfly?

Tags: apache, ssl, wildfly-9, ajp

Setting up a public Wildfly (9.0.2.Final) server, I'm figuring out the
alternatives for doing this with or without Apache as a front towards
Internet. I'd prefer to use Apache as this solves other problems for
me.

I should say: I need to use SSL for securing the data traffic.

I've set up SSL for both Wildfly and Apache.

Looking through blogs and tutorials, I haven't found an alternative
that performs SSL between Apache and Wildfly. That would seem to be a
preferred choice for me, where there one.

I've tried and configured

1. Configuring Apache using mod_proxy_ajp. This prohibits me from
   using SSL between Apache and Wildfly but allow me to close the
   firewall for 8080 and 8443.
2. Configuring Apache using `mod_proxy_http`. This gets me the
   `Exception` of `no secure port to forward to` on the Wildfly side
   which seems not to have any solution.
3. Open up the Wildfly ports 8080 and 8443 and letting requsts go
   directly to a publicly exposed Wildfly, ehich I hear is not
   recommended.

Since all three alternatives have their drawbacks, I got to ask: How are people usually doing this?